# text does not preserve color when printing - Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function calc_total() {
  $("#total").text(formatCurrency(parseFloat($("#netPerW").text().replace(",", "")) + parseFloat($("#netPerC").text().replace(",", "")) + parseFloat($("#netPerSB").text().replace(",", "")) + parseFloat($("#netPerDB").text().replace(",", ""))));
  Total = parseFloat($("#netPerW").text().replace(",", "")) + parseFloat($("#netPerC").text().replace(",", "")) + parseFloat($("#netPerSB").text().replace(",", "")) + parseFloat($("#netPerDB").text().replace(",", ""));
  if (Total > 0) {
    $('#total').css('color', 'green');
    }
  else {
    $('#total').css('color', 'red');
  }
}
```

Above is my function to calculate the total and change the text color depending on the condition but when I try to print, the colors all revert back to default black.

```
@media print {
#total {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
  }
}
```

I've tried many different variations of this but to no effect.

Is there anyway I could add a style tag to the html or javascript to accomplish my goals of preserving the color of text when printing?

Comment: Is the entire document in black and white? Or just these specific elements?  (You shouldn't need to do anything specific in the CSS to allow color printing; if it's the full document check to make sure you're not printing in grayscale mode or something...)

Comment: The document has varying gray background colors for different sections and the only text that is colored is the 'net totals' depending on positive (green) or negative (red) but when I try to print the page, all background colors turn to white and all text turns to black

Comment: @Bkass sounds like a printer setting. Have you tried printing on a different printer?

Comment: I've tried different printers and print to PDF